# Why Docker is not getting installed

Tags: docker, installation

[image]

while installing docker I get stuck in this part when I execute the .exe docker how much does docker weigh? my PC is not slow why is docker getting stuck in this screen

the screen doesn't even close I have to go to end tasks to end this process